# に particle and passive form.... multiple meanings?

Tags: particles

There's a sentence in my textbook.

子供の時から今までを振り返って男あるいは女に生まれて、Ａよかったと思った／思うこと、Ｂ嫌いだと思った／思うこと、を三つずつ書いてください

男あるいは女に生まれて、 This is the part in particular I don't understand... I read it as... "Born by a man, or possibly a woman..." Why would it say that? Is it supposed to be read "Born AS a man or possibly a woman?"

Don't tell me that 女に生まれる has two meanings!!! It means born by right? に is supposed to be actor of the passive action right? Like 巨人に食べられた。... Or am I somehow wrong.

Comment: So out of curiosity, what does the OP's sentence mean? How does 男あるいは女に生まれて fit into my attempt at the translation:

"Looking back from childhood to present, please write down for each case three examples of things/events A) you like/liked B) you don't or didn't like."

Adding "born as a male or female" seems a bit pointless?

Comment: @MobiusPizza:  It means three things you liked about and three things you didn't like; specifically about being a male/female.  Not just three arbitrary things.  Ex:  "As a young boy, I liked not having to wear dresses.  I hated having to hold the door open for older women though."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xに生まれる is syntactically ambiguous between:

1. Born as a X

   - 女に生まれる (be born as a woman)
2. Born to a X

   - 裕福な家庭に生まれる (be born to a wealthy family)
   - 女に生まれる (be born to a woman)

For (1), think of adverb+verb. (E.g. Run quickly) ( ✕ Born woman-ly → ◯ born as a woman)

And for (2) think of a intransitive verb acting with a indirect object (e.g. Bob lied(verb) to Mary(indirect object))

Comment: Thankyou.... Damn particles... Whenever I start to think I understand them.... more exceptions... everywhere... It's impossible :(

Comment: @Nathan Same problems in English. *By* sunrise, everyone will know he was killed *by* a bullet, fighting *by* the side of his comrades.

Comment: Yeah... you are right :(... I will prevail thanks for the wake up call!